# How to create an entity relationship between an abstract class and a concrete class in a java spring-boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, annotations

For example when I have below classes

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public BaseEntity(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
//@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Artwork extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "style_id")
    private Style style;

    //  private ARTIST TODO;

    public Artwork(Long id, String name, Style style) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.style = style;
    }

    public abstract int calculateCost();
}
```

---

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "styles")
public class Style extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artwork")
//    @JoinTable("artwork_id")
    private List<Artwork> artwork;
}
```

In my project I will have different kinds of artworks and each of them will have a `Style`. So at first, my `Artwork` class was a `@MappedSuperClass`, but after getting an error and doing some googling, I learned that to be able to define a relation through `Artwork`, I had to make it an `@Entity` and add the `@Inheritance` annotation to get a similar functionality as `@MappedSuperClass` (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

But now I still can't get what I wanted because there must be a table name for `@JoinTable` in `Style`.
So, is there a way of achieving what I'm trying? Or is it just a bad practice to do this? Should I be specifying each relation separately (writing each `Artwork` type to `Style` as attribute and assign the relation to each of them)?

Comment: Could you try with an unidirectional ManyToOne ? That is you remove the OneToMany in Style class.

Comment: @g.momo I could, but what if I want to keep the bidirectional relation, is specifying each relation separately the only way?

Comment: I just ask for you to detect if the problem is exactly there or elsewhere. Test a bit.

Comment: Oh I see. So when I removed `OneToMany` line in `Style` it says `Basic' attribute type should not be a container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible with the `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy as you can't model a single FK to multiple tables in SQL. You could use the `JOINED` inheritance strategy instead.